# How to Use Trigger to Log Changes in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

`Users` table:

[image]

`LoginLog` table:

[image]

How can I log Name, Password, LastLogonTime to `LoginLog` table when `Users` table `LastLogonTime` column is updated and insert a row?

Comment: *Why* are you storing passwords in plain text in the first place? **Never** do that. Hash the passwords with a salt and store those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a fairly simple trigger on the update of the `Users` table. The trickier part is being aware of the fact that triggers are fired **only once** for each statement - and such a statement could potentially update **multiple rows** which would then be in your `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables in the trigger.

You need to write your trigger to be **aware** of this set-based manner and handle it correctly. In order to be properly able to link the old and new values, your table `Users` **must have** a proper primary key (you didn't mention anything about that) - something like a `UserId` or the like.

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_LogUserLogon
ON dbo.Users
FOR UPDATE
AS
    -- inspect the Inserted (new values, after UPDATE) and Deleted (old values, before UPDATE) 
    -- pseudo tables to find out which rows have had an update in the LastLogonTime column
    INSERT INTO dbo.LoginLog (Name, Password, LastLogonTime) 
        SELECT
            i.Name, i.Password, i.LastLogonTime
        FROM
            Inserted i
        INNER JOIN
            -- join the two sets of data on the primary key (which you didn't specify)
            -- could be i.UserId = d.UserId or something similar
            Deleted d on i.PrimaryKey = d.PrimaryKey
        WHERE
            -- only select those rows that have had an update in the LastLogonTime column
            i.LastLogonTime <> d.LastLogonTime
```

But please also **by all means** take @Larnu's comments about not ***EVER*** storing passwords in plain text into account! This is really a horribly bad thing to do and needs to be avoided **at all costs**.

Comment: Considering how often data breaches with plain text passwords are in the news recently, and how slated companies/people are that are foolish enough to do it, it honestly concerns me howany people continue to make the same old mistakes...

Comment: @Larnu: couldn't agree more - it boggles my mind